# snap a smaller grid to a larger predefined grid using xarray

Tags: python-xarray, reindex

I have a code as below.
So basically i have predefined a grid, and i make a loop every single small grid to this larger predefined grid. But the code stuck at the reindex part.it just using too much memory and it crushed.Is there other way i can snap the small grid to a larger grid?

```
latitudes=np.linspace(20.0000,50.0000,100001)

longitudes=np.linspace(-130.0000,-100.0000,100001)

AREASCORE=np.full((100001,100001),255,dtype=np.uint8)

AREAFUEL=np.full((100001,100001),255,dtype=np.uint8)

datasets_WFHS= xr.DataArray(AREASCORE,name='AREASCORE',dims='latitude','longitude'],coords={'latitude':latitudes,'longitude':longitudes})

print ("created empty array")





for d in glob.glob(r'Z:\travelers\shp\test\*WFHS.nc'):

    d=xr.open_dataset(d)

    d=d.reindex({'latitude': latitudes, 'longitude': longitudes}, method='nearest', tolerance=0.0001)

    print ('done reindex')

    d=d.fillna(255).astype(np.uint8)

    print ("done fillna")

    datasets_WFHS = xr.where(d==255, datasets_WFHS['AREASCORE'], d['AREASCORE'])

    print ("done np where")
```

Answer (score 0):

You are making some gigantic arrays here -- an array with shape `(100001, 100001)` and `uint8` dtype requires 10 GB to represent in memory. Typically you need at least 3-4x the size of your largest arrays to comfortably manipulate arrays with NumPy, so I would not be surprised if this fails on any machine with less than about 64 GB of total RAM.

You should try [opening your datasets with dask](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/dask.html#reading-and-writing-data), which works with xarray to support working with arrays larger than fit into memory. This could be as simple as adding a `chunks` argument to your call to `xr.open_dataset()`.

Comment: but i only tried with 2 small grid. The code not even pass one loop. the create empty array part is works fast. but not reindex part

Comment: It's also quite likely that `reindex` uses more memory than simply allocating an array with `np.full()`. It's doing a lot more work to reorder all of the data.

Comment: so xarray no other packages can do this.